# (Highly dynamic) environment variables in Postman

Tags: postman

Postman supports setting environment variables and using them in, say, headers.

Consider the following example:

1. Token endpoint `/auth/token` requires basic `Authorization` header: `Basic {{AUTH_BASIC}}`
2. All other endpoints requires bearer `Authorization` header: `Bearer {{AUTH_TOKEN}}`

Currently, I need to go through all the following steps, which is very annoying:

1. Call `/auth/token`
2. Manually copy the token from the response
3. Go to `Settings > Manage Environments > MyEnvironment`
4. Paste the token against `AUTH_TOKEN` and click `Update`

Is there a way to automatically update the `AUTH_TOKEN` environment variable each time when I call `/auth/token` or at least always display list of current environment variables so I can manually update values without going to `Settings > Manage Environments > MyEnvironment`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering the `/auth/token` response is something like:

```
{
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9"
}
```

Go to the **Tests** tab of `/auth/token` endpoint and paste the following:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("AUTH_TOKEN", jsonData.token);
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone landing here in the future, you can now accomplish this with the following:

```
var response = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set('AUTH_TOKEN', response.token);
```